# What unit does PowerPoint's XML use for label offsets?

Tags: powerpoint, openxml, python-pptx

I'm attempting to programmatically adjust the offset of PowerPoint data labels based on their length. I can edit the XML to whatever I want using Python, but I'm having trouble figuring out the units and how to get the correct values.

**XML that Creates a ~0.69 inch offset to the right**

```
<c:manualLayout>
    <c:x val="5.6138097651134596E-2"/>
    <c:y val="0"/>
</c:manualLayout>
```

**XML that Creates a ~1.16 inch offset to the right**

```
<c:manualLayout>
    <c:x val="9.5554208767888671E-2"/>
    <c:y val="0"/>
</c:manualLayout>
```

Unless I'm missing something (entirely possible), I can't get these values to line up. It doesn't seem to line up with [DXAs or EMUs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360183/default-wordml-unit-measurement-pixel-or-point-or-inches), [Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251649/what-is-the-unit-of-measure-for-powerpoint-slides-using-vba), or anything else I can find. I'd love to convert inches to this unit, as inches are used in other parts of the code.

Comment: Looks like it's a percentage, 5.614% and 9.555%, respectively. In this case, check your Left Mode (`c:xMode`). Is it "factor"? If so, then the position is relative to the default position for the chart element

Comment: The only xMode I could find was in relation to a different element's offsets, and it was "edge." Percentage might make sense, but I'm having trouble discovering what it's a percentage of. If there's only one xMode per document, that would mean it's a percent of the edge of the shape container?

Comment: Hi Todd, can you add this as an answer? I've discovered that you're correct. They're percents of the shape container holding the chart and thus the labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely a percentage offset, based off of `c:xMode`.